# Fundamental Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning, problem-solving

> Determine $\phi(x,0)$ for $A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & \cos(x) \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, where $\phi(x,0)t_{0}$ is a solution of $\frac{d}{dx}t(x)=A(x)t(x)$.

I am not entirely sure as to how to proceed when $A$ is not constant. What I know is that if $A$ had been constant then I would first begin by determining the eigensystem of $A$ and multiply this by its inverse, from the right, to get $\phi$. Now, since $A$ is not constant, I presume one still can do this, but that the inverse of the eigensystem will depend on $x_{0}=0$. If so, then I get the following result:

**Edit - Wrong matrix**

I noticed I calculated the eigenvalues and their respective eigenvectors on the wrong matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \cos(x) \\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} e^{x}-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}\cos(x) &-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}\cos(x) \\ -1 &-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} e^{x}&-\frac{\cos(x)}{2}e^{-x} \\ 0 &e^{-x} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Done. Now your turn.

Comment: @Artem I gave it a try.

Comment: You should start with the second equation, and then solve the first one.

Comment: @Artem I know that if $A$ is a constant matrix then $\phi(x,x_{0})=\exp (A(x-x_{0}))$ is the principal fundamental matrix of the system $\frac{d}{dx}t(x)=At(x)$. Now, if $A(x)$ is not constant then I presume we need to find a *fundamental matrix*, $\psi(x)$. Is this not found by calculating the eigenvalues, and their corresponding eigenvectors to form $\psi(x)$ before multiplying (from the right) with $\psi(x_{0})$, such that $\phi(x,x_{0})=\psi(x)\psi^{-1}(x_{0})$?

Comment: @RiEanalysis While technically this works, here the second equation describes the evolution of $t_2(x)$ entirely in terms of $t_2(x)$. As a consequence it can be solved separately and its solution substituted into the first equation. Indeed, if $\cos(x)$ were any nonzero constant, you would find that in fact the equation you have written is already in Jordan canonical form, that is, already in the best form to use to compute the matrix exponential.

Comment: @Ian If I understand correctly, we need to find the solution corresponding to the initial conditions $x(t_0)=\delta_{1}=(1,0)$ respectively $x(t_0)=\delta_{2}=(0,1)$. I shall keep $t_{0}$ for now, as I need to grasp the technique.  In the first case $x(t_0)=\delta_{1}$, the second equation gives $x_{2}(t)=0$ and plugging this into the first equation shows $x_{1}(t)=e^{-t-t_{0}}$, that is, $\phi(t,t_{0},\delta_{1})=(e^{-t-t_{0}},0)$. Similarly, in the second case $x(t_{0})=(0,1)$, the second equation gives $x_{2}(t)=e^{-(t-t_{0})}$. How do I use this to determine $x_{1}(t)$?